# how to apply wireless proxy setting to my android app

Tags: android, proxy

I have an Android phone, which I use for development at college, which uses a proxy server on their network. Whenever I open a web browser on my device, a popup dialog prompting me for authentication, then I can connect to the network. But apps on my phone cannot seem to connect.

After searching in google for a while, I know that android apps are not proxy aware by default, but is there any **android api** which can accept my authentication and make it possible, like `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy` in C#? Btw, I would like to implement it in my android project and not any other app installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I find this method is the key.

`public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view,
            HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm)`

Then fill the authentication by calling `handler.proceed(username, password)`.